# MySQL update decimal values of decimal type so all values end in .95

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a very simple table with a column named `price`. `price` is a decimal type. Let's say I want to change all the prices so that they end in `.95`. So `5.00`, `5.50`, and `5.99` all become `5.95`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of the [floor()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) function.

```
UPDATE `my_table`
SET
price = floor(`price`) + 0.95
```

If you allow null on the field, you may want to check by adding `AND price IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Watch out for edge cases, like zero and NULL prices.

Comment: I mean not that `FLOOR()` won't work, but that a free product suddenly costs a lot more.

Comment: @tadman running `SELECT FLOOR(0.00)` gives me 0. I've put in a note about NULL. Thanks!

Comment: If you had a product that was "free with X purchase" you're going to make it cost money now, which could come as a rude surprise.

Comment: I think you'll want to check that. It converts `0.00` to `0.95`.